# Verifying mean and covariance estimators of a two-dimensional normal distribution

Tags: python, estimation, estimators

Here I try to verify estimators of the mean and covariance matrix of the two-dimensional normal distribution $N(\mu, A)$ with $\mu=[-2,3]^T$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 11\\
11 & 25 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an i.i.d. samples from $N(\mu, A)$. Here my estimators are given by $\hat{\mu}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/n$ and $\hat{A}=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i- \hat \mu)(x_i-\hat \mu)^T/(n-1)$.

My question is that my result is very different from the true value... Is this a normal phenomenon?

Here is my code and output:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
def Data(n):
  mu=np.array([-2.0,3.0])
  A=np.array([[1.0,2.0], [3.0,4.0]])
  X=np.random.normal(size=n*2)
  X=X.reshape((n,2))
  X=(X+mu).dot(A)
  return(X.T)

data = Data(10000)

mu_hat = np.mean(data, axis=1)
sigma_hat = np.cov(data)
```

**output is as follows:**

```
mu_hat=[7.02352613 8.04361423]
```

```
A_hat=[[10.11067835 14.20627231]
 [14.20627231 20.35677073]]
```

I also checked the MSE as follows:

```
MSE for mean: 53.43103419753712
MSE for covariance matrix: 17.05974388551374
```

Comment: What do you understand the "true values" to be?  The mean of your distribution is *not* equal to the entries in `mu` because you have multiplied them by `A`.  Notice that $$\mu A=\pmatrix{-2&3}\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4}=\pmatrix{7&8}.$$ (The "$A$" in your question evidently is $AA^\prime.$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that if $\tilde X \sim \mathcal N_2(0, I)$, then $A\tilde X + \mu \mathrel{=:}Y\sim \mathcal N_2(\mu, AA^\top)$.

Starting from $n$ realizations of $\tilde X$ stored *row-wise* in a matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times 2}$, you can therefore generate $n$ realizations of $Y$ (stored row-wise in a corresponding matrix) by first right-multiplying $X$ by $A^\top$ and then adding $\mathbf 1_n \mu^\top$ (where $\mathbf 1_n$ is a column vector whose $n$ entries are all $1$s) to the resulting matrix.

In your code you would have to change the line

```
X=(X+mu).dot(A)
```

to something like

```
X = X.dot(A.T) + mu
```

to reflect this.

Comment: I didn't check the code and OP edited the question later. This answers clearly the problem. I have deleted mine (which only addressed the initial query). +1.

Comment: Wait. Is my code wrong? It seems that `X=(X+mu).dot(A)`?

Comment: @H.YDuan, please check the definition of [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector), which is already pointed out by statmerkur in their post at the very beginning.

Comment: @H.YDuan With `X=(X+mu).dot(A)` your code generates `n` realizations of a $
\mathop{\mathcal N}\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
3
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$-distributed random variable.